# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 500, size is 1 while using retrofit callback inside for loop

Tags: java, android, callback, retrofit

I am trying to fetch data from api using **retrofit** and use `ArrayList` to store data, size of `ArrayList` is 500 after fetching data from api. On trying to log the items from `ArrayList` my app crash and I am getting

> error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 500, size is
>   1

I think problem is due to variable int i. Please correct me where I am wrong and guide me how to solve this problem.

```
private int i = 0;
private void get() {
    // size of newList is 500
    for ( i = 0; i < newList.size(); i++) { 
        apiService.getNewStories(newStoryIdList.get(i), new Callback<Story>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Story story, Response response) {
                listStory.add(story);
                Log.d("newListItems" ,+listStory.get(i).toString()); // getting error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 500, size is 1
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the size of `newList` is 500? The error is telling us the size is 1.

Comment: Would you be able to post the code showing how `newList` is made and populated?

Comment: The error could be on "newStoryIdList.get(i)". Are your sure that this list has 500 itens?

Comment: You have three lists  - newlist, newStoryIdList, listStory and you are using index i for all of them. Are you sure that this is what you want to do?

Comment: Ah yes, didn't catch that a different list was being used in that line.

OP, that is your problem, you are either using the wrong list (you want to use `newList` where you use `listStory` or you forgot to populate `listStory`

Comment: by the time you call `listStory.get(i)`, i is 500, but `listStory` is still mostly empty.

Comment: yes the size of newList is 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking the size of the newList resolve my problem. If size of newList is greater than 0 then for loop will execute otherwise not.

```
private int i = 0;
private void get() {
    if(newList.size() > 0) {
       for ( i = 0; i < newList.size(); i++) { 
          apiService.getNewStories(newStoryIdList.get(i), new  Callback<Story>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Story story, Response response) {
                  listStory.add(story);
                  Log.d("newListItems" ,+listStory.get(i).toString()); 
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        }
    });
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line:
`apiService.getNewStories(newStoryIdList.get(i), new Callback<Story>() {`

Without the definition of `apiService.getNewStories` I can suppose that you need to use `apiService.getNewStories(newStoryIdList, new Callback<Story>() {` instead ?

Comment: apiService is a interface having getNewStories ()

Answer (score 0):

i guess the problem is, that your variable `i` is at the value of 500, when the callback will arrive, because your `for-loop` will increase it locally

after the callback will come back, and add 1 `story` to `listStory` `i` is still at value 500 and you call `listStory.get(i).toString()` on a list, that has only 1 value at that time

EDIT: Solution:
remove the debug-output, or write:

```
Log.d("newListItems" ,story.toString());
```

Comment: yes that's the problem please help me to solve this. Should I use another variable instead of i or use i

Comment: you don't have a problem, simply remove the debug-output, or just call `story.toString()`

Comment: yes that solve my problem but i want to use listStory outside success() is it possible. Actually after adding all items to listStory I want to sort it and display sorted liststory.

Answer (score -1):

newList may be of size 500, but what about newStoryIdList?